# how to call a service using ajax javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, web-services

I'm learning programing, could you explain me how to call a service using ajax javascript?

Service information:

- Service type: REST
- Basic authentication
- Estructure: Application/JSON
- Url: https://osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/AdministradorFotografiasJsonPS/fotos/consultar
- User: Admi
- Password: admi
- Parameter JSON example: {"identificacion":["98122811999"]}

I've tested this service in postman
[image]

Service answer:

```
{
    "respuesta": [
        {
            "estado": "Correcto.",
            "identificacion": "98122811999",
            "imagen": "return string Base 64 format"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Find all the information you need here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery :

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/AdministradorFotografiasJsonPS/fotos/consultar',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{"identificacion":["98122811999"]}
    contentType: "application/json"
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("admi", "admi"));
    },
    success: function (data,status) {
     //do what you want with the data after success
     //in this example the response will be promoted in the browser console
     console.log(data);
    });
});

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return 'Basic ' + hash;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Momo Setti appear this error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'osb.urosario.edu.co/uxxi-URO/WsFotografias/proxy/…' from origin 'urosario.edu.co' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: hi @FelipeMoreno. your welcome any time, you should just fix/by-pass the CROS feature, its provided by browsers to ensure the user client security.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your above RestEndpoint using below:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/EndpointURI", true);
 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
        //Use parse() method to convert JSON string to JSON object
        var responseJsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 
        //use response
    }
};
 
var jsonData = {"name" : "yourData"};
xmlhttp.send( JSON.stringify( jsonData ) );
```

For Authentication use this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://EndPointURI", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa('userName:password'));
xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send();
```

For authentication part, use JQuery then it will easy for the implementation and as well for understanding. as now aday no body use basic xmlhttp for calling api in javascript, last time i used was a 2003 developed application.